# Centering input element into horizontal form Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have horizontal form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email and other some many texts and some one else and else and else and else</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

How to center input to label?

[image: See]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVdu4/)

**UPD: Pls try on jsfiddle beforу answer.**

Comment: How about adding some margin to the top of the `<input>` element?

Comment: My labels has diferent length. I need dynamic varint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't know if you want to use javascript, but in case you want, here is what you have to do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var height = $('#inputEmail3').parent().prev().height();
    var dif = height - $('#inputEmail3').height();
    var margin = dif / 2;
    $('#inputEmail3').css('margin-top', margin);
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/2Z53G/) is the example. By the way, i don't recomand you use col-sm-2 class on the label insted of a div.

If you want this script to be universal, just use this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
        var height = $(this).parent().prev().height(); 
        var dif = height - $(this).height();
        var margin = dif / 2;
        $(this).css('margin-top', margin);
    });
});
```

And the result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/9742c/)

Comment: " By the way, i don't recomand you use col-sm-2 class on the label insted of a div." - but its from official documentation. Your example is not bad, but I need universal solution. Not for few row.

Comment: Well it's not very complicated to make it universal, for example remove the id and add a same class to all the inputs from the right column, and use that class in the javascript.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle for that and updated the answer. You can now add as many fields as you want and they will be automaticaly verticaly aligned.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by making `.form-group` a table by doing `display:table;`, and then apply `vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell;` to your `.centering` class.

That should work, or at least push you into the right direction.

Comment: There many other problem with form-group after adding display:table

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the child `label` and `div` as `inline-block`. They can then be vertically aligned:

```
.form-group > label, .form-group > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4Y6R/

EDIT: I've also added an arbitary `max-width` to the label (although I assume you've already sized your labels and fields as required)

Comment: Do you try add http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css to your example? It's didn't work

Comment: @IgorShubin - I didn't add it to my example but I have now and it STILL works for me.